# how to delete failed pipeline in azure data factory in monitor window

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-monitor

I am trying to delete the pipeline from the azure data factory in the monitor tab, but it is not showing the delete option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete pipeline run history, Data Factory removes these records automatically after 45 days.

If you meant to delete the actual pipeline, you can do that in the author pane.